# JSON_DECODE returning NULL from cURL response even though encode format seems correct?

Tags: php, json, curl, post

**EDIT: For the solution, view reply from Barmar below. Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.**

I'm trying to take a login from my test.php file and cURL it to a site which uses the data to simulate a login on another page (I know this is tedious, but this isn't the full extent of what I'm doing as a whole, just where I have the problem). So I post an encoded json to the index.php url which has no problem decoding it. The information passed is then used and the decoded json is edited to show successful or unsuccessful login. The json is then encoded once again and echoed onto the page and held in $contents on test.php. When I try to decode it on this file I get NULL everytime. I've tried a ton of things and am just starting to think I made a stupid mistake somewhere so I'm desperately looking for any help here.

-If I echo $contents it shows:

```
 {"user":"user","pass":"password","success":true}
```

-If I var_dump(trim($contents)) it shows (formatted exactly as shown):

```
 string(364) "
 {"user":"user","pass":"password","success":true} "
```

-last_json_error_msg shows:

```
 SYNTAX ERROR
```

-I've tried trimming, utfencoding, iconv, setting curl headers and literally everything I've seen recommended on other posts here.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.

test.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method=POST>
        <input type="text" name="user">
        <input type="password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    function logInfo(){
        class data{
          public $user = "";
          public $pass = "";
          public $success = false;
        }

        $data = new data();
        $data->user = $_POST['user'];
        $data->pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $ch = curl_init();
        $json = json_encode($data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, [URL TO INDEX.PHP]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("data"=>$json));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $contents = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $array = json_decode($contents, true);
        var_dump($array);
        //VAR_DUMP SHOWS NULL
    }

    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
        logInfo();
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="test.php" method=POST>
                <input type="hidden" name="data">
            </form>
            <?php
            header('Context-type: application/json');
            function logInfo(){
                    $datastring = $_POST['data'];
                    $data = json_decode($datastring);

                    $ch = curl_init();

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, [URL TO SIMULATE LOGIN]);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [LOGIN POST]);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


                    if($code == [SUCCESSFUL LOGIN HTTP CODE]){
                            $data->success = true;
                    } else {
                            $data->success = false;
                    }

                    echo json_encode($data);
                    curl_close ($ch);
            }
            if(isset($_POST['data'])){
                logInfo();
            }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT: For the solution, view reply from Barmar below. Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.php` is printing HTML before the JSON (weren't you suspicious when `var_dump()` said that the string is 365 characters long, but you can only see about 50?). When the script is being used to return JSON, it can't produce any other output.

So check for the `data` parameter before printing any output. And if it's found, exit the script after sending the JSON, so you don't print the HTML.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    logInfo();
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="test.php" method=POST>
                <input type="hidden" name="data">
            </form>
            <?php
    </body>
</html>
<?php
function logInfo(){
    header('Context-type: application/json');
    $datastring = $_POST['data'];
    $data = json_decode($datastring);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, [URL TO SIMULATE LOGIN]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [LOGIN POST]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


    if($code == [SUCCESSFUL LOGIN HTTP CODE]){
        $data->success = true;
    } else {
        $data->success = false;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

A simpler solution would probably be to put the code that returns `logInfo()` into a different script.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still getting NULL returned unfortunately.

Comment: You should look at the output of `var_dump()` with `View Source`, in case there are other HTML elements.

Comment: EDIT: Used different login information on test with edited code, var_dump($contents) shows the same.

Comment: You still see all the HTML when you view the source?

Comment: I removed all HTML from the page entirely. Was able to get it working after that. Never would have gotten it if you didn't bring my attention to HTML being return in the cURL. Thanks a ton. I have never worked with PHP so trying to figure this out was a serious grind.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why my version didn't work. Are you sure you have the `exit()` line in the `if` block?

Comment: I sincerely apologize, but in my scramble to find solutions for some reason I never noticed the exit() line you added. After adding that it does indeed work with the HTML still present. Thanks so much again.

Comment: I've made the answer clearer about that part of the change.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
json_encode(get_object_vars($data));
```

in logInfo function

A couple of things I would recommend. It's not a good practice to define a class inside a function. You should have your class in a separate file. It helps keep your code organised.

Secondly, its good to follow either snake case or camel case for defining classes / methods / functions etc.

Snake case eg: my_function_name_to_execute
Camel case eg: MyFunctionNameToExecute

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to define the class at all. He could just use a simple associative array. They both produce the same JSON.

Comment: Changed up all you said. Thanks for the help. Still getting NULL on decode unfortunately.

Comment: His problem is with `json_decode()`, not `json_encode()`. Why do you think changing the object that's being encoded will make a difference?

Comment: @Barmar It was created when I was attempting different approaches and I left it for no real reason.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check resulting JSON syntax using this library https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint

**UPDATE**

It correctly detects extra HTML from `index.php` and other possible problems.

Following example

```
use Seld\JsonLint\JsonParser;
$parser = new JsonParser();
$exception = $parser->lint('<html>{"user":"user","pass":"password","success":true}');
echo $exception->getMessage();
```

will output:

```
Parse error on line 1:
<html>{"user":"user"
^
Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```